# Inherited Attributes Access

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

How do you access inherited attributes in java outside the constructor?

```
public PainelPrincipal(Jogo jogo,GridPanel gridPanelPrincipal) {
    super(jogo,gridPanelPrincipal);
    listaBlocos = new LinkedList<>();

    carregarFicheiroNivel();
    gridPanelPrincipal.setEventHandler(this);
}

private void carregarFicheiroNivel() {
    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("/niveis/EstadoInicial.txt");
    String conteudo = handler.readFile();
    String[] colunas = null;

    int y=0;
    for(String linha: conteudo.split("\n")){
        colunas = linha.split(" ");
        for(int x = 0; x < colunas.length; x++) {
            if(colunas[x].substring(1, 2).equals(PAREDE)){
                grelha[x][y] = new Parede();
                gridPanelPrincipal.put(0, 0, grelha[0][0].getCellRepresentation());
            }else{
                switch(colunas[x].substring(0, 1)){
                    case "0":break;
                }
            }
        }
        y++;
    }
}
```

This line **gridPanelPrincipal.put(0, 0, grelha[0][0].getCellRepresentation());** doesn't seem to work, he doesn't recognize the **gridPanelPrincipal** variable outside the constructor of the class.

Is it possible to access it outside the constructor or how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access it outside the constructor, because presumably it's `private`.  You can only access it in the constructor because it's an argument to the constructor.

You can either:

1. Make the proper variable `protected` in the superclass to make it visible to the subclass, OR
2. (Kind of kludgy) Create your own variable in your subclass to store its own reference to the `GridPanel`, so you can access it in other methods.

Comment: with protected value in the superclass i must use the actual name of that variable in the superclass instead of the name that i gave to it in this class that extends from it. Is it the same variable? Instead of using gridPanelPrincipal that i get from superclass i have to use gridPanel that is the variable passed through the super. So i assume it is the same right?

Comment: Assuming that the superclass constructor assigns this variable to the `private`, now `protected`, instance variable, then you use the same variable name as the instance variable.  Technically it's not the same variable as the parameter to your constructor.  But they should be variables referring to the same object.